# How to get nextauth jwt token to backend

Tags: express, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I have a nextjs application, where I use nextauth for login. The rest of the application backend is in express.js.

How do I send a jwt token from nextauth to this backend when doing API call from front end in the header of the call to protect api routes in express.js.

Here is my next-auth route, where i cant figure out how to return jwt token to session so i can use the token for api calls.

```
export const authOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        // Check if getting credentials
        if (!credentials.email || !credentials.password) {
          throw new Error("err");
        }

        // Check if user exist
        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: { email: credentials.email },
        });

        if (!user) {
          throw new Error(
            "err"
          );
        }

        // Check if password match
        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.hashedPassword
        );

        if (!passwordMatch) {
          throw new Error(
            "err"
          );
        }

        // Return user object
        return { id: user._id, email: user.email, role: user.role };
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ token, session }) {
      if (token) {
        session.user.id = token.id;
        session.user.email = token.email;
        session.user.role = token.role;
      }

      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      const dbUser = await prisma.user.findFirst({
        where: { email: token.email },
      });

      if (!user) {
        token.id = user && user.id;
        return token;
      }

      return {
        id: dbUser.id,
        email: dbUser.email,
        role: dbUser.role,
      };
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
```

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the opposite.
For example, you can fetch to your express backend in the `authorize` function and do the login operation in express, without reaching the DB and do that directly in the `authorize` function.

before when using next12, I was doing this.

```js
//....
 async authorize(credentials) {
        // Check if getting credentials
        if (!credentials.email || !credentials.password) {
          throw new Error("err");
        }

        // Check if user exist
        //const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        //  where: { email: credentials.email },
        //});
        // instead of checking user here. Do that in express
        const res = await fetch('path-to-your-backend-url', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({ ...yourData }),
          //.... rest of configurations
        })
        const data = await res.json()
        
        // Then based on response do your logics and if every thing is ok, so you can complete the login operation and let user in.
        
        if (res.error) {
          throw new Error(String(res.error))
        }
        // Return user object if every thing is ok!
        return { id: user._id, email: user.email, role: user.role };
 },
//....
```